# JSONObject how to store null value

Tags: json, liferay-6

I am using **com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject** in liferay 6.2 and I want to store null value in an object of this type as mentioned below

```
`JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();`  
`jsonObject.put("name","varun")`
`jsonObject.put("address",null)`
```

As in **org.json.JSONObject** we can set null by JSONObject.NULL

Is there any way to set null in liferay JSONObject?

Comment: Why can't you use `org.json.JSONObject.NULL` for `com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject.put` as well? I know, it is cumbersome, but at least it works. You could introduce your own constant for it to circumvent the package reference.

Answer (score 2):

The Liferay object wraps only the [com.liferay.portal.json.JSONObjectImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.0.2/com/liferay/portal/json/JSONObjectImpl.java#JSONObjectImpl.0_jsonObj)
As Tobias said you can use the JSONObject.NULL

Another thing is, do you really need to set this? Usually, parsers just null the fields if they don't find them.

Comment: `jsonObject.put("address", (String) null)` is much easier to read. But unfortunately this will _not_ work, see `org.json.JSONObject.put(String, Object)`: `if (value != null) { ... } else { this.remove(key); }`. The only option is `jsonObject.put("address", org.json.JSONObject.NULL)`

Comment: Yes, you are right I check only the Liferay source code.